# Angular2 - Router navigate with param (RC.4)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm working on the new router with RC.4, on the http error codes. I'm trying to send a parameter through the URL but I have a "character issue"...

Here is my call : `this._router.navigate(['/error', { errorCode: '401' }]);`

And this is the URL, which contains a ";" instead of a "?" : `http://localhost:3000/error;errorCode=401`

What I want : `http://localhost:3000/error?errorCode=401`

Because when I am reading this URL, it only works with this "?" :

```
this._router.routerState.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        let errorCode = params['errorCode'];
        ...
```

(Optional - app.routes.ts) :

```
{
    path: 'error',
    component: ErrorComponent
},
```

I searched on internet but didn't find anything about it, how can I change the ";" or maybe how can I read `error;errorCode=401` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add them to a root route, then the parameters are added as query parameters (using `?`). On child routes they are added as matrix parameters (using `;`).

Therefore if you want to add it as query parameters, then you need to add them to the root routes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! There is a way to read matrix parameters in angular2 ?

Comment: They work the same as (actually are) query parameters, just the representation in the URL is different depending on what route they are applied.

Comment: What do you mean by adding them to the main route? Do you mean registering routes in submodules with RouterModule.forRoot()?

Comment: Sorry, I meant root routes (top-level routes)

Answer (score 0):

```
let queryParams = {
  status: 1,
  string: 'abc',
};
this._router.navigate(['/path'], { queryParams: queryParams });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.